# Executing 3rd Party Powershell SDK commands with C#

Tags: c#, powershell, citrix

This is an incredibly frustrating problem that nobody else seems to have the answer to so I'm trying to break my question down into the simplest thing possible. Surely there are other 3rd party Powershell SDK's out there that people have tried to access and use via C#.  Does anybody know why this would get an error saying the following?

`The term 'add-PSSnapin Citrix*.Admin.V* is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

The same goes for other commands that this PSSnapin provides at the command prompt.

I can type this command in manually at a powershell command prompt and it works. So do the other commands. What's the deal?

```
public void testPS()
        {
            using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
            {
                runspace.Open();
                PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
                ps.Runspace = runspace;
                ps.AddCommand("add-PSSnapin Citrix.*.Admin.V*");
                ps.Invoke();
                //Commented sections below don't work either, same error. 
                //ps.AddCommand("Get-BrokerSession");
                //ps.AddParameter("AdminAddress");
                //ps.AddParameter("SERVERNAME");
                //ps.Invoke();
                //Collection<PSObject> psr = ps.Invoke();
                //foreach (PSObject x in psr)
                //{
                //    MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
                //}
            }
        }
```

UPDATE:

This new code as suggested in the answer below gets a new error: `'System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll`

```
public void testPS()
        {
            using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
            {
                runspace.Open();
                PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
                ps.Runspace = runspace;
                PSSnapInException psex;
                runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn("Citrix.Broker.Admin.V2", out psex);
                Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

                Command getSession = new Command("Get-BrokerSession");
                getSession.Parameters.Add("AdminAddress");
                getSession.Parameters.Add("MYSERVERNAME");
                //also tried the above with this code
                //getSession.Parameters.Add("-AdminAddress MYSERVERNAME");
                // and
                //getSession.Parameters.Add("AdminAddress MYSERVERNAME");
                // and other methods as well
                pipeline.Commands.Add(getSession);

                //This line below is where the exception occurs.
                Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();

                foreach (PSObject x in output)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

UPDATE 2:

I also get this same error above trying to set the execution policy.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE 3:

Fixed, see comments in answer below. The syntax of the parameters line was incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn` to add PSSnapin and then add a command:

```
        Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runSpace.Open();
        PSSnapInException psex;
        runSpace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn("Citrix.Broker.Admin.V2", out psex);
        Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();

        Command getSession = new Command("Get-BrokerSession");
        getSession.Parameters.Add("AdminAddress", "SERVERNAME");
        pipeline.Commands.Add(getSession);

        Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();
```

Comment: Thanks, we're so close. Then I get the error "Windows PowerShell snap-in names can only contain alpha-numeric characters, dashes, underscores and periods." Which is utter bs because that's not true, asterisks are used quite often and I just did it at the command prompt. So that makes no sense.

Comment: If you have limited number of snapins, then just specify exact names instead of wildcards.

Comment: True, we may almost have this, but now when just using the specific snapin "Citrix.Broker.Admin.V2" I'm getting "'System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll" when using your method above. I'll update my post with the new code.

Comment: Do you get such exception only for this specific snapin or for every one? Which version of System.Management.Automation you linked to your project?

Comment: I get the exception with others but in those cases it's because the command isn't found, this command is only in that snapin. Not sure about the version, this is Visual Studio 2015. Maybe this is a security issue? Not sure how to set the security to unrestricted in this context if so.

Comment: Fixed, answer was the Parameters syntax, it should be like this: getSession.Parameters.Add("-AdminAddress", serverName);

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you split the command from its argument. In your case, it would be something like:

```
ps.AddCommand("add-PSSnapin");
```

Then you can always just post-append `Citrix.*.Admin.V*` as an argument for the command above.

Comment: Getting close. "Windows PowerShell snap-in names can only contain alpha-numeric characters, dashes, underscores and periods." WTF?

Answer (score 0):

For those still stuck with this like me, even as of the latest Microsoft.Powershell.Sdk 6.2.0 nuget package I was running into this issue. A colleague of mine ended up getting it to work by doing the following:

```
    public string RunPowershell(string param1)
    {
        var outputString = "";

        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = @"powershell.exe",
            Arguments = "C:\\path\\to\\script.ps1" + " -param1  " + param1,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();

            var output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            var errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
            {
                outputString = output;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errors))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {errors}");
            }
        }

        return outputString;
    }
```

"C:\path\to\script.ps1" can have Add-PSSnapin commands in it and still run just fine.

I couldn't find a bug filed for Microsoft.Powershell.Sdk to handle this, but if someone creates one and links it here, thanks!

Hope this helps